# AutoCompleteTextView OnItemClickListener does not work

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a specific question today and I searched on google but could not find any answer that could help.

My activity has an AsyncTask that loads some strings from database and shows them in autocompletetextview. Im using HttpUrlConnection for getting the strings, then parsing them using json-simple library and then showing them in autocompletetextview. Here is the whole code for ACTV which is in onPostExecute():

```
ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Shift_OneTime sot : shifts) {
     result.add(sot.getName() + " " + sot.getDay() + " " + sot.getMonth() + " " + sot.getYear());
     }
     for (Employee e : emps) {
         result.add(e.toString());
     }

     acs = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocompletesearch);

     ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainScreen.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
     acs.setAdapter(adapter);
     acs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               acs.setText("");
               acs.clearFocus();
               Object o = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
               if (o instanceof Employee) {
                  Intent n = new Intent(MainScreen.this, EmployeeDetailsActivity.class);
                  n.putExtra("employeeid", ((Employee) o).getId());
                  startActivity(n);
                } else if (o instanceof Shift_OneTime) {
                  Intent n = new Intent(MainScreen.this, ShiftDetailsActivity.class);
                  n.putExtra("shiftid", ((Shift_OneTime) o).getId());
                  startActivity(n);
                }
           }
      });
```

Im getting this bunch of warnings:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

These errors appear when I click on string that shows up after typing something into autocompletetextview. Now my observation is not certain, but last time it was working I was using the old DefaultHTTPClient or whatever is was that is now deprecated. That is the reason I changed to HttpURLConnection. After this change, I also moved the ACTV to the AsyncTask as Im reading the strings from my php webservice, and I also added ActionBarDrawerToggle and overrode its methods so the soft keyboard hides when I open the navigation drawer.

I tried to remove the extended toggle and I also tried to put the onItemClickListener() back outside of AsyncTask, but it did not help. I cant really go back to the deprecated HTTP client now, so I would like to know if anyone has any ideas... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you need to use setOnClickListener();

Comment: no, setOnClickListener reacts when you click on ACTV. That is not what i want

Comment: ur are missing and else just to be sure u get the right stuff

Comment: i had it there before, and none of the ifs were processed, but that else was

Answer (score 0):

The problem I did not notice is that `Object o = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);` was getting an object of type String (notice the way i populate 'result' list), neither an object of Employee nor Shift_OneTime. So when I checked if 'o instanceof XXX', it was neither one or other. So instead of filling the list with strings, I had to insert the objects themselves,f.e.:
Before:

```
result.add(sot.getName() + .... );
```

After:

```
result.add(e);
```

The search of characters in ACTV is done using values in toString() method in Employee and Shift_OneTime classes.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things and i found this solution

I did this solution when Onclicklistener wasn't working on my code

Put Onclicklistener in your custom adapter in getView().

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Customer customer = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customer_row, parent, false);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(yourContext, "text clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

//....do your stuff here 

        return convertView;
    }
```